# When testing NodeJS how hard to go with NodeJS built-in assert comparing to other packages

Tags: node.js, testing, assert

There are a lot of famous and well-supported testing packages out there to test NodeJS applications. But NodeJS gives us an inbuilt `assert` module. I want to know to what extent can we use it to test NodeJS applications by considering time, complexity, and ultimately cost wise. And are there any advantages of the `assert` module?
What is your recommendation based on your experience?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html)?

Comment: yes I have gone through